# I have message incompatible types

Tags: delphi

```
  TServiceData = class  
  strict private
    FPriority: Integer;
    ...
  public
    property Priority: Integer read FPriority write FPriority;
    ...
  end;

  TMonthData = class  
  strict private

    function GetServiceData(AIdx: Integer): TServiceData;
  public
    ...
    property ServiceData: TServiceData read GetlstServiceData;  // incompatible types - Why?
  end;
```

Sorry. Typing error. Original

```
property ServiceData: TServiceData read GetServiceData;
```

Comment: I wonder, why the DV's?

Comment: I did not DV, but i can try to guess few potential reasons: maybe they were for not reading basic documentation? Or for not even giving minimal text what what TS is even asking about? Maybe because he did not formatted sources and made them hard to read? Or because the title of the question conveys no information? Who knows...  www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I assume you did not copy and paste this from your actual code? Because you have a private method called `GetServiceData` (with a parameter?), but declare `GetlstServiceData` (IOW, different name) as the getter.

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not have argument in the property.

`property ServiceData: TServiceData read GetlstServiceData;`

See - the `GetlstServiceData` here can have no arguments because Delphi has nowhere to take them from its only available information source at compile type - the very `property ServiceData: TServiceData` declaration.

You should either add the argument to the property or to remove it from the function.

```
 TMonthData = class  
  strict private

    function GetValue0Args(): TServiceData;
    function GetValue1Arg(const AIdx: Integer): TServiceData;
    function GetValue2Args(const AIdx: Integer; const Flavour: string): TServiceData;
  public
    ...
    property Data0Args: TServiceData read GetValue0Args;  
    property Data1Arg[ SlotNumber: integer ]:  TServiceData read GetValue1Arg;  
    property Data2Args[ SNum: integer; Recipient: string ]:  TServiceData read GetValue2Args;  
  end;
```

See so called "array properties": http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Properties#Array_Properties

Though "array properties" are not actually arrays. The term was poorly selected: arrays would never take complex entities like strings or objects as their index while properties and functions do take them as their possible arguments.